# Memory leak with stringWithCString

Tags: iphone, memory-management

Hi all i am getting memory leaks with following lines of code .how to solve ....

```
const char *value = (const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, i);
[result setObject:[NSString stringWithCString:value encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] forKey:columnName];
```

or

```
const char *value = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, i);
NSString *str_Value = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:value]] ;
[result setObject:str_Value forKey:columnName];
[str_Value release];
```

how to remove this leaks .please help out......

Comment: As for the first one: Are you sure this is the leak and how?
As for the second: You certainly need [str_Value release]; at the end.

Comment: The first version looks just fine. The second version is also correct (after the edit) although the explicit `initWithFormat:` is unnecessary as all it does is wrap the string returned by `stringWithUTF8String:`. So, where does Instruments say is the leak?

Comment: at [result setObject:str_Value forKey:columnName];

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. What kind of object is leaked? And which version of the code you've posted are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to null check for it;

```
if (value != null)
{
   NSString *str_Value = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[NSString 
   stringWithUTF8String:value]] ;
  [result setObject:str_Value forKey:columnName];
}
```

Comment: While that certainly is a good idea, you still miss the leaking NSString.